# Wordpress insert new user not adding in backend

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

When signing up on my dev site, a bug is here that i cant seem to figure out. I am allowed to pass the validation when signing up. But when i use the submit button to create the account, it seems to not want to log any information into the database. I get the logged in message but that's it, i can just recreate the 
same over ad over again.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxregister', 'ajax_register' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxregister', 'ajax_register' );

function ajax_register() {

    $title          = $_POST['titles'];
    $firstname      = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname       = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email          = $_POST['user_email'];
    $user_pass      = $_POST['user_pass'];
    $confirm_pass   = $_POST['confirm_pass'];
    $agree_tc       = $_POST['agree_tc'];
    $nationality    = $_POST['nationality'];
    $username       = $_POST['user_email'];//strtolower($firstname) . '-' . strtolower($lastname);
    $phone          = '+' . $_POST['country_code'] . $_POST['phone'];
    //$address        = $_POST['address'];

    if ($user_pass != $confirm_pass || !is_email($email) || $agree_tc != 'true') {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin' => false, 'message' => __('There are some errors')));
    } else {

        $user = array(
            'user_login'    => $username,
            'user_pass'     => $user_pass,
            'first_name'    => $firstname,
            'last_name'     => $lastname,
            'user_email'    => $email,
            'role'          => 'client'
        );

        $user_id = wp_insert_user($user);

        if (is_wp_error($user_id)) {

            $error_string = $user_id->get_error_message();
            echo json_encode(array('loggedin' => false, 'message' => $error_string));

        } else {

            update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_num', $phone);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_nat', $nationality);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'display_titles',$title);
            //update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_address', $address);

            $creds = array(
                'user_login'    => $username,
                'user_password' => $user_pass
            );

            $user_signon = wp_signon($creds, false);
            echo json_encode(array('loggedin' => true, 'message' => __('Login successful, redirecting...')));

        }
    }

    die();
}
```

EDIT .

The markup was perfectly fine, however after going through my repo of changes. The display titles was not getting parsed.

```
function ajax_register() {
    $title          = $_POST['titles'];
    $firstname      = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname       = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email          = $_POST['user_email'];
    $confirm_email  = $_POST['confirm_email'];
    $user_pass      = $_POST['user_pass'];
    $confirm_pass   = $_POST['confirm_pass'];
    $agree_tc       = $_POST['agree_tc'];
    $nationality    = $_POST['nationality'];
    $username       = $_POST['user_email'];
    $phone          = '+' . $_POST['country_code'] . $_POST['phone'];
    if ($user_pass != $confirm_pass || !is_email($email) || !is_numeric($_POST['phone']) || $agree_tc != 'true') {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin' => false, 'message' => __('There are some errors')));
    } else {
        $user = array(
            'user_login'    => $username,
            'user_pass'     => $user_pass,
            'first_name'    => $firstname,
            'last_name'     => $lastname,
            'user_email'    => $email,
            'display_titles'=>$title, // THIS WAS MISSING 
            'role'          => 'client'
        );
        $user_id = wp_insert_user($user);
        if (is_wp_error($user_id)) {
            $error_string = $user_id->get_error_message();
            echo json_encode(array('loggedin' => false, 'message' => $error_string));
        } else {
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_num', $phone);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_nat', $nationality);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'display_titles',$title);
            //update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_address', $address);
            $creds = array(
                'user_login'    => $username,
                'user_password' => $user_pass
            );
            $user_signon = wp_signon($creds, false);
            echo json_encode(array('loggedin' => true, 'message' => __('Login successful, redirecting...')));
        }
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript to submit the form -via- Ajax?

Comment: I found the misplaced code. Was in my functions

Comment: And?  Care to share it.

Comment: will update my code today. sorry was busy yesterday